# How to display images from a DB using masonry in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, masonry

I want to display almost 1000 images from a custom database that I already have. I want to display them using the plugin `masonry`. I mean instead of display posts or pages, display images - is that possible? Now I don't mind if there are 3 or 4 columns, I just want to display them in masonry. The images from my database have an ID.

I already did it in local host , by which I mean I have a .php file that displays all these images. I don't know if this is an issue of a function that calls a .php file or if I have to code some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In your php file import wp-load.php and use the wordpress database object like a global variable (global $wpdb).

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb; //wordpress database object

$query = "Select * from";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: in my php file ? , but i did it in local host , not in wordpress , where should i paste my php file ? , i'm sorry , i don't get it at all , i'm kinda new in Wordpress

Comment: Like this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57526/add-a-menu-item-to-navigation-menu-to-link-to-external-url

Comment: Kinda , but i just wanna display each image from my db in each different post , im trying but i don't get it yet

Comment: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/pluto-clean-personal-wordpress-masonry-blog-theme/full_screen_preview/7950280